# Error converting a word document to pdf using apache-POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to convert a word document to pdf using apache-POI, but I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

This is my code:

```java
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\2161-1041-5-157.docx"));
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);

// 2) Prepare Pdf options
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

// 3) Convert XWPFDocument to Pdf
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\2161-1041-5-157.pdf"));
PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
```

The full exception and callstack is:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V  at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.parseRelationshipsPart(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationshipCollection.(PackageRelationshipCollection.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.loadRelationships(PackagePart.java:561)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.(PackagePart.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackagePart.(ZipPackagePart.java:78)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:696)
>     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:280)
>     at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.(XWPFDocument.java:128)
>     at org.open.word.POIWordToPDF.createPDF(POIWordToPDF.java:27)   at
>   org.open.word.POIWordToPDF.main(POIWordToPDF.java:18)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like incompatible jars. Add the complete stacktrace if you Need help by finding out which one

Comment: please check my above printStackTrace output

Comment: Can you also Show which poi.jars you use?

Comment: Are you sure that you have all POI jars in the same version in your classpath? No duplicates?

Comment: above are my poi jar versions

Comment: What happens [when you follow the advice in the Apache POI FAQ entry for this topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)?

Comment: I have done some reformatting of your code extracts, and retitled the question, to make it a little clearer.